# Conditionally displaying list of items based on passed prop values in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuetify.js

I created this simple card component:

`Card.vue`

```
<template>
            <v-card :loading="loading">
                <v-card-text v-if="!loading">
                    <div class="text-center font-weight-black title text--primary">
                        {{data}} {{unit}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        {{title}}
                    </div>
                </v-card-text>
            </v-card>
</template>
```

To this component I pass the following props:

`props: ['title', "data", "unit", "loading"]`

Now in parent component I use v-for to create list of the above component:

```
 <Card
          v-for="d in basic_fc"
          v-bind:key="d.id"
          v-bind:title="d.title"
          v-bind:data="d.data"
          v-bind:unit="d.unit"
          v-bind:loading="loading"
          :class="'home__simple-finance--'+d.id"
 ></Card>
```

and computed properties:

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters(["basic_fc"]),
  loading () {
      if (this.basic_fc.length==0) {
        return true
      } 
      else {
        return false
      }
    }
  }
```

Now the `basic_fc` is a vuex getter that returns an array of values. The thing is this array can be empty, so when it is empty the `loading` variable is `true` and vice versa.

So the expected behavior is that the `Card.vue` component is shown but as empty card. Passing `loading` value to the `v-card` and `v-card-text` works if its single component but somehow it does not for a list.
So how can I make it so that the list of cards is rendered anyway?

Comment: You can simplify your `loading` property to `return this.basic_fc.length === 0` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v-for` is a for loop. If the list is empty then it wont run even once that is why you do not get any cards.I hope i got your question right

You could do something like this

```
<div v-if="!loading">
 <Card
      v-for="d in basic_fc"
      :key="d.id"
      :title="d.title"
      :data="d.data"
      :unit="d.unit"
      :loading="loading"
      :class="'home__simple-finance--'+d.id"
  ></Card>
</div>
<div v-else>
  <Card
      :loading="loading"
      :class="'home__simple-finance--'+d.id"
  ></Card>
</div>
```

PS: `v-bind:{{param}}` is same as `:{{param}}`

Comment: *`v-bind:{{param}}` is same as `:{{param}}`*, true but many linters aren't happy about the simplified form ;)

Comment: true! just added that coz i replaced `v-bind:` from the question to `:` , wouldn't want anyone to get confused

Answer (score 1):

You should do the logic of `computed` variable `loading` in v-card component, not in parent component. its not a good practice to pass as props a computed property.

Comment: I also thought of this, but that computed value is relying on the value that is empty so even if I put computed logic inside child component then I think it wont be computed at all